# HTTP Status 404 on jsp spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm trying to develop a spring MVC project which has a index.jsp file as it's view. I searched and found I should do this by the help of two below configuration classes:

```
public class MainInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    public static HashMap<String, String> response_code = new HashMap<String, String>();


    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { MainConfiguration.class,
        WebSocketConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        servletContext.addListener(new MainContextListener());
}
}
```

and this is MainConfiguration class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "-----")
public class MainConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/Content/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/Content/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/Scripts/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/Scripts/");

    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
                = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

I've configured my project to run on tomcat web-server inside intellij. but when index.jsp is directly in path : webapp/index.jsp it will be opened in browser after running the program but when I move it to a subfolder it doesn't.

Shouldn't this part of code give the address to spring so it find the url and don't give a 404 error?

```
 viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
```

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your MainConfiguration.java with `@Configuration.` Also, you require to register an instance of the `DispatcherServlet` in the servlet context. Actually, you can refer - [spring mvc with jsp example](http://www.devglan.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-annotation-example) for detailed configurations.

Comment: I've been missing @Configuration when posting the question, I corrected it. and about registering an instance of DispatcherServlet  I've refered to [link](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-helloworld-tutorial-annotation-javaconfig-full-example/) , in this link it's said that u can use MainInitializer class that extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer instead of implementing WebApplicationInitializer.